# Gaussian integral: $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2\left\{ \Phi (a + b x) \right\}^2 \phi(x) \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, approximation

Is there an analytic solution for the following integral?

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \left\{ \Phi (a + b x) \right\}^2 \phi(x) \mathrm{d}x,$$

where $\Phi(\cdot)$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ are the cdf and pdf respectively of the standard normal.

Wikipedia has a list of related integrals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) but not the one I want to compute.

Does anyone have a way to solve this integral analytically? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Here we appreciate *context* and your own *thoughts* or *attempts*. Unfortunately this question will get closed otherwise, so to prevent this, please include more information into your question body.

Comment: By $\Phi(a+bx)^2$ did you really mean $\Phi((a+bx)^2)$? Because otherwise this integral certainly won't have a closed form.

Comment: $ \Phi (a + b x)^2$ means $ \left\{ \Phi (a + b x) \right\} ^2$. I modified the formula to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Does $\{.\}$ mean the fractional part of the function or are they just parentheses?

Comment: Just parentheses.

Comment: It would help if you wrote out what the functions $\phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x)$ are

Comment: $ \Phi(x) $ and $ \phi(x) $ are the cdf and pdf respectively of the standard normal. $ \phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2}) $, $\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t) \mathrm{d}t $.

Comment: The integral without the $x^2$ term is evaluated analytically in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039). Thus $K(c)=\int dx \ [\operatorname{erf}(ax+b)]^2 e^{-cx^2}$ is known. Even though the result in the linked post has an $\operatorname{erfc}$, it may be cast in the form of your integral using the first result. Your integral is then given by $-\partial_c K(c)|_{c=1}$. The result will likely not be pretty.

Comment: An integral similar to that, $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \Phi (a + b x) \phi(x) \mathrm{d}x$, has been posted. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027470/second-moment-of-the-product-of-normal-cdf-pdf