# Definite integral of the normal CDF times the normal PDF

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution

I have a question very similar to [this one here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433204/definite-integral-of-a-product-of-normal-pdf-and-cdf/2129112#2129112?newreg=f4a28b925cd24e0f955bfba138cb64db), except I'm looking for a *lower*-bounded integral instead of an upper-bounded one. Specifically, I need to find

$$\int_y^\infty \phi(x) \Phi\left(\frac{x-b}{a} \right)dx$$
I understand that Owen (Comm. in Stat., 1980) probably has this integral solved, but unfortunately, my university library is closed for COVID-19, so I can't get my hands on a copy of it. I'm sure it's very similar to one of the answers in the link above but I can't figure it out.

My best attempt is that, following similar reasoning in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/61098) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434260), what I'm looking for is $P(X \leq Y \cup Y \geq y)$, where $Y \sim N(0,1)$, $X \sim N(b,a^2)$. I'm not exactly sure where to go from here. I could use the multiplication rule to say that
$$P(X \leq Y \cup Y \geq y) = P(X \leq Y)P(Y \geq y|X\leq Y)$$
or
$$P(X \leq Y \cup Y \geq y)=P(Y \geq y)P(X\leq Y|Y \geq y)$$
but I'm not sure where to go from here or if this step is even useful

Comment: You could try taking the complement of the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283928/closed-form-solution-for-an-integral-involving-the-p-d-f-and-c-d-f-of-a-n0-1) and change the parameters inside $\Phi$ appropriately.

Comment: I'd seen that answer but I hadn't thought about taking the complement. So basically, the answer is just $1-BvN\left[\frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}, y; \rho= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right]$, where $BvN(w,z,\rho)$ refers to the bivariate normal with correlation $\rho$?

Comment: Sorry, turns out I was wrong: that integral over $\mathbb{R}$ isn't one, but it can be found in Lemma 1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04736.pdf. Take what you get here minus the BvN term.

Comment: Ah, right, so it would be basically my answer in my previous comment, but instead of 1, I would use $\Phi \left( \frac{-a}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}\right)$. So the full answer would be$$\int_y^\infty \phi(x) \Phi\left(\frac{x-b}{a} \right)dx = \Phi \left( \frac{-a}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}\right) - BvN\left[\frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}, y; \rho= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right]$$